# wrong indexPath.row in UITableView ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am building an iphone application, i have an array with 99 records when i run my app then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method return  `indexPath.row` from 0 to 7.  here is my code below

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [[accountParser accounts]count];//it return 99 records
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

       NSLog(@"Index : %d",indexPath.row);//this print index 0 to 7 only


    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Put the NSLog outside the if-statement since right now it only logs rows that are not re-using a cell view.

Comment: TableView cell are Reuse that's why that's why print only 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you display your UITableView, it only calls tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: for visible rows. It means that it will call the other rows (8 to 99 in your case) only when you will scroll the view.